# RapidMiner Not Connecting To SQL Server Database Connection

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

I recently installed RapidMiner and tried connecting the application to my MS SQL database connection via the Manage Database Connections feature. I have followed video tutorials on integrating SQL Server but i keep getting errors on connecting to localhost, and port 1433.

I have checked to see if SQL Server browser was running. It is. My TCP/IP connection is enabled, and also my default port is 1433. So what can be the problem?

I use mixed authentication with SQL Management Studio, i added the same in the Manage DB Connection form. But i keep getting an error:

> "The TCP/IP connection to the localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error:
>   Conection refused. connect"

I tried using Microsoft SQL Server (JTDS) as DB system (I downloaded JTDS from Sourceforge),  but i keep getting a

> "Network error IOException: Connection refused:connect"

Please, I'd really appreciate help because it's left me frustrated as i need this application to work for some project i am undertaking.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database directly through Management Studio using the same login?

Comment: Yes i am. I don't have any issues logging into SQL Management Studio

Comment: If using kerberos/integratedSecurity, your JTDS URL should look like:

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostname/dbname;domain=$domain;user=$username;password=$password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if TCP-IP is enabled with SQL Server Configuration Manager. [Run SQL Server Configuration Manager for different versions of SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx).

Then [Edit TCP-IP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx) and go to IPAll and set TCP-IP port to 1433 and Dynamic port to 0, then restart SQL Server service.